# Hold the console window open using c#

Tags: c#, windows, console

I have the below code to build a project using MSBuild:

```
string process = sourcePath + @"\Application.sln /t:rebuild";
System.Diagnostics.Process csc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe",process);
```

This code worked before, I don't know why is not working any more.

If I do the same thing above by CMD it works fine, but not from VS.Net, the console window disappear fast so I can't see the error message.

If I debug the code I got this:
`BasePriority = 'csc.BasePriority' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`

Is there any way to hold that screen so I can know what is happening here?

Comment: If it was worked BEFORE 100% you have to restart your computer...

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the line that is throwing the error?

Comment: @valverij see the part `If I debug...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start the cmd process with MSBuild.exe as an argument instead of directly starting the exe file.

```
string process = @"C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe " + sourcePath + @" \Application.sln /t:rebuild";
System.Diagnostics.Process csc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe", process);
```

Comment: I don't understand :( My app is a console window that calls another console window app. The last one is the one I need to be active so I can see the error.

Comment: The MSBuild.exe process exits immediately when the build completes. The console you want to see is actually the cmd process window that runned the MSBuild.exe process. I do exactly this: run the MsBuild process from the newly created cmd console window. Or do you need to see the output in console windows of your own process - it would be a bit harder - you need to copy the output of that process (ran silently) and output it to your own console

Comment: Thank you @OleksandrPshenychnyy your solution made me see my issue, a space was missing between MSBuild.exe and the rest of the path

Comment: =))). It is always easier to see the misteke in someone's code than in your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to redirect the output of the msbuild you start using [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = sourcePath + @"\Application.sln /t:rebuild";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I got an error: `MSBuild: error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.` Why is this happening, there is only one project here. :(

Comment: It happens when you have space in your paths.. Need double quotes around it.. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/470659/158297 and also http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/tfs-2010-msbuild-error-msb1008-only-one-project-can-be-specified/

Comment: Awesome @Amitd, that finally fixed it. I was placing the folder in path: like `Doument and Settings...` that was causing that error, so I moved it to a folder in `c:\temp\...` without spaces :)